# UML for a sharepoint project or application

Tags: sharepoint, uml

Is there an modelling approach like UML (i.e Class diagrams, use-cases, etc.) for a Sharepoint project or application? Or, are there other methods for this kind of project that are different from UML?

Comment: What is "Sharepoint project(application)"?

Comment: a Sharepoint application or a Sharepoint project

Comment: thanks Gangnus, I m old in this superbe forum, but i was inactive for a long time :)

Answer (score 1):

UML is a language set, supporting modelling. Not modelling in some specific language, let alone programming language. I often use class diagrams for modelling UI design or user guides.

Sharepoint is a language, supporting creation some kinds of IS, with some functionalities enhanced, some diminished. Modeling of such IS can be done fully with the use of UML. Use of UC, components diagrams, class diagrams, object diagrams and ALL other structural diagrams is obvious. The use of behavioral diagrams is more limited, simpler Sharepoint systems needn't special behavioral modelling.

Comment: So the sharepoint application support the uml approache, Have you an example of that, a simple class digramm of a sharepoint application plz

Comment: @Issibra Create any diagram with reference(s) to some specific structure or functionality of sharepoint. Thus you'll create a diagram that is obviously intended for a sharepoint application.

Comment: yeah i know, but the the thing that appears a bit weird is to create a diagramm of the functionnality already exist in sharepoint, and especially that we have with sharepoint new concepts such as the notion of the Site, Site collection, subsite, I have no clear idea about these things
thanks

Comment: You don't need to create diagrams for functionalities or structures that are provided by sharepoint. You should use these as ready whole blocks in your diagrams explaining and supporting YOUR functionalities and structures. For example, if you are deriving YourClass from some SharepointClass, you use both on the class diagram, but don't show classes that are used in some way by SharepointClass, even its own members should be shown only if you need it for better understanding.